# Add a text on a plotted dot in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application.so what i need to do is plot a dot according to the xy coordinates and pop up a text when click on that name.I plotted a dot but i still searching a way to popup a text on it. if someone can please help me.

Comment: I believe not a dot, but circle?

Comment: Looks like we need a clarification - I'd say some images would be nice.

Comment: sure i use a circle.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you drawing on a canvas? if so

when intializing vars:

```
TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
```

and in your onDraw:

```
canvas.drawText("You're Text",dot.x,dot.y,tp);
```

you might change the y so its not right on the dot, and maybe the color like so:

```
tp.setColor(Color.RED);
 canvas.drawText("You're Text",dot.x,dot.y-10,tp);
```

you can make it "pop-up" when you select the "dot" using onTouch and simple booleans.